# .net services.AddHttpClient Automatic Access Token Handling

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to write a Blazor app that uses client secret credentials to get an access token for the API.  I wanted to encapsulate it in such a way that it handles the token fetching and refreshing behind the scenes.  To achieve this, I created the following inherited class which uses IdentityModel Nuget package:

```
public class MPSHttpClient : HttpClient
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
    private readonly TokenProvider Tokens;
    private readonly ILogger Logger;

    public MPSHttpClient(IConfiguration configuration, TokenProvider tokens, ILogger logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Tokens = tokens;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<bool> RefreshTokens()
    {
        if (Tokens.RefreshToken == null)
            return false;

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(Configuration["Settings:Authority"]);
        if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

        var result = await client.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = Configuration["Settings:ClientID"],
            RefreshToken = Tokens.RefreshToken
        });

        Logger.LogInformation("Refresh Token Result {0}", result.IsError);

        if (result.IsError)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Error: {0)", result.ErrorDescription);

            return false;
        }

        Tokens.RefreshToken = result.RefreshToken;
        Tokens.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;

        Logger.LogInformation("Access Token: {0}", result.AccessToken);
        Logger.LogInformation("Refresh Token: {0}" , result.RefreshToken);

        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckTokens()
    {
        if (await RefreshTokens())
            return true;


        var client = new HttpClient();

        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(Configuration["Settings:Authority"]);
        if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

        var result = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = Configuration["Settings:ClientID"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Settings:ClientSecret"]
        });

        if (result.IsError)
        {
            //Log("Error: " + result.Error);
            return false;
        }

        Tokens.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
        Tokens.RefreshToken = result.RefreshToken;

        return true;
    }


    public new async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Tokens.AccessToken);

        var response = await base.GetAsync(requestUri);

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            if (await CheckTokens())
            {
                DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Tokens.AccessToken);

                response = await base.GetAsync(requestUri);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

The idea is to keep from having to write a bunch of redundant code to try the API, then request/refresh the token if you are unauthorized.  I tried it at first using extension methods to HttpClient, but there was no good way to inject the Configuration into a static class.

So my Service code is written as this:

```
public interface IEngineListService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<EngineList>> GetEngineList();
}

public class EngineListService : IEngineListService
{
    private readonly MPSHttpClient _httpClient;

    public EngineListService(MPSHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    async Task<IEnumerable<EngineList>> IEngineListService.GetEngineList()
    {
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<EngineList>>
            (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/EngineLists"), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
}
```

Everything compiles great.  In my Startup, I have the following code:

```
        services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();

        services.AddHttpClient<IEngineListService, EngineListService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"]);
        });
```

Just to be complete, Token Provider looks like this:

```
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the App, it complains that it can't find a suitable constructor for EngineListService in the call to services.AddHttpClient.  Is there a way to pass AddHttpClient an actual instance of the IEngineListService.  Any other way I might be able to achieve this?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: What do you think you are going to win using an httpclient that inherits an original one? Would not it to be easier to use a composition instead of inheritance, especially since net core has a special httpclient factory?

Comment: By using `new` you aren't overriding the method. So when you have an HttpClient reference it won't call your method. And AddHttpClient will only add normal HttpClient (not a subclass)... But! This is exactly the case for a DelegatingHandler... Which has built in support in conjunction with AddHttpClient

Comment: @Serge What do you mean by Composition instead of Inheritance?  What I am trying to win is that I can make normal calls to a child of an HttpHandler and it takes care of getting the tokens for me.  Any call to GetAsync() would automatically check the access token and update if needed.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 This is true that if MPSHttpHandler gets cast to an HttpHandler, the base methods will be called.  can you give me more info on a Delegation Handler?

Comment: @JimWilcox   You can see one of the composions in  Rosco  answer. I only think maybe it makes sense to merge EngineListService with MPSHttpClient too.

Comment: https://www.techwatching.dev/posts/delegating-handler see the section later in the blog with the title "using a delegating handler" or pretty much the entirety of this of one https://blog.joaograssi.com/typed-httpclient-with-messagehandler-getting-accesstokens-from-identityserver/

Comment: I also strongly recommend that you use a custom delegating handler rather than deriving from `HttpClient`.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you from the Dark Side of the Moon, bro.  That second blog you linked was exactly what I needed.  I really had to make very few changes to my code.  I had to inherit DelegatingHandler in MPSHttpClient and fix a few other things and it worked.  I will post the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @pinkfloydx33 for helping me solve this.  This link that he shared https://blog.joaograssi.com/typed-httpclient-with-messagehandler-getting-accesstokens-from-identityserver/ was everything I needed.  The trick was that there exists a class called DelegatingHandler that you can inherit and override the OnSendAsync method and do all of your token-checking there before sending it to the final HttpHandler.  So my new MPSHttpClient class is as so:

```
public class MPSHttpClient : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
    private readonly TokenProvider Tokens;
    private readonly ILogger<MPSHttpClient> Logger;
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public MPSHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration, TokenProvider tokens, ILogger<MPSHttpClient> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Tokens = tokens;
        Logger = logger;
        client = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckTokens()
    {
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(Configuration["Settings:Authority"]);
        if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

        var result = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = Configuration["Settings:ClientID"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Settings:ClientSecret"]
        });

        if (result.IsError)
        {
            //Log("Error: " + result.Error);
            return false;
        }

        Tokens.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
        Tokens.RefreshToken = result.RefreshToken;

        return true;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBearerToken(Tokens.AccessToken);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            if (await CheckTokens())
            {
                request.SetBearerToken(Tokens.AccessToken);

                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

The big changes here are the inheritance and I used DI to obtain the HttpClient much like @Rosco mentioned.  I had tried to override OnGetAsync in my original version.  When inheriting from DelegatingHandler, all you have to override is OnSendAsync.  This will handle all of your get, put, post, and deletes from your HttpContext all in one method.

My EngineList Service is written as if there were no tokens to be considered, which was my original goal:

```
public interface IEngineListService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<EngineList>> GetEngineList();
}

public class EngineListService : IEngineListService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public EngineListService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    async Task<IEnumerable<EngineList>> IEngineListService.GetEngineList()
    {
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<EngineList>>
            (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/EngineLists"), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
}
```

The Token Provider stayed the same.  I plan to add expirations and such to it, but it works as is:

```
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

The ConfigureServices code changed just a bit:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    ...

        services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();

        services.AddTransient<MPSHttpClient>();

        services.AddHttpClient<IEngineListService, EngineListService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"]);
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MPSHttpClient>();

     ...
     }
```

You instantiate MPSHttpClient as Transient, then reference it with the AddHttpMessageHandler call attached to the AddHttpClient call.  I know this is different than how others implement HttpClients, but I learned this method of creating client services from a Pluralsight video and have been using it for everything.  I create a separate Service for each entity in the database.  If say I wanted to do tires, I would add the following to ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddHttpClient<ITireListService, TireListService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"]);
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MPSHttpClient>();
```

It will use the same DelegatingHandler so I can just keep adding services for each entity type while no longer worrying about tokens.  Thanks to everyone that responded.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: You're still a bit backwards. You shouldn't be accepting an httpclient inside of your delegating handler. The httpclient uses the handlers (essentially a chain of them make up a client). You did the DI registration stuff right.. But from within the handler you have access to send async and that's all you need. I think you're ending up with a loop (ie every http call invokes the handler twice)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I see what you mean, but that isn't happening.  I set some breakpoints and SendAsync is not getting called during the HTTP requests in the CheckTokens function.  I think the reason is that my handler is only getting wired up for EngineListService, so the HttpClient passed to my handler isn't wired up go through my handler.  I need an HttpClient because the IdentityModel functions are extensions for HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `EngineListService` should not be registered as a `HttpClient` in services and instead you should register `MPSHttpClient`.

This follows the "Typed Client" example in the documentation and uses `IHttpClientFactory` behind the scenes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests#typed-clients

When you use `services.AddHttpClient` the constructor needs a `HttpClient` parameter. That is how the `HttpClientFactory` initializes the `HttpClient` and then passes it into your service ready to go.

You can change your `MPSHttpClient` to not inherit `HttpClient` and instead add a `HttpClient` parameter to the constructor. You could also have it implement an interface like `IMPSHttpClient`

```cs
public class MPSHttpClient
{
    public MPSHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration, TokenProvider tokens, ILogger logger)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        Configuration = configuration;
        Tokens = tokens;
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

You must remove these lines from `MPSHttpClient` and use the injected client.

```cs
// remove this
var client = new HttpClient();
```

In Startup add

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<MPSHttpClient>(client =>
{
    // add any configuration 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"]);
});
```

Change EngineListService to a normal service registration as it is not a HttpClient

```
services.AddScoped<IEngineListService, EngineListService>()
```

Comment: My method for adding a handler is the standard from the docs, only I used a MPSHttpClient instead of an HttpClient.  In your case, I still need to add the IEngineListService in the startup somewhere.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: I think since net core is used maybe it is better to inject httpClientFactory instead of httpClient?  Http client you can create inside of the constructor

Comment: I've added a link to the docs to show it uses IHttpClientFactory when you call AddHttpClient() and registration for IEngineListService